# How a participant be a part of multiple conversations in Twilio

Tags: twilio, twilio-api, twilio-php, twilio-programmable-chat

How a participant is a part of multiple conversations in Twilio. I am trying to add one participant in multiple conversations in Twilio. Please help me.

Comment: Is that participant a chat participant? (via the Conversations SDK)?

Comment: Can you share the code you are using and the error messages you receive?